# Microservices Architecture: Cross Service data sharing

Tags: web-services, architecture, microservices

Consider the following micro services for an online store project:
Users Service keeps account data about the store's users (including first name, last name, email address, etc')

Purchase Service keeps track of details about user's purchases.

Each service provides a UI for viewing and managing it's relevant entities.
The Purchase Service index page lists purchases. Each purchase item should have the following fields:
id, full name of purchasing user, purchased item title and price.
Furthermore, as part of the index page, I'd like to have a search box to let the store manager search purchases by purchasing user name.

It is not clear to me how to get back data which the Purchase Service does not hold - for example: a user's full name.
The problem gets worse when trying to do more complicated things like search purchases by purchasing user name.

I figured that I can obviously solve this by syncing users between the two services by broadcasting some sort of event on user creation (and saving only the relevant user properties on the Purchase Service end). That's far from ideal in my perspective. How do you deal with this when you have millions of users? would you create millions of records in each service which consumes users data?

Another obvious option is exposing an API at the Users Service end which brings back user details based on given ids. That means that every page load in the Purchase Service, I'll have to make a call to the Users Service in order to get the right user names. Not ideal, but I can live with it.

What about implementing a purchase search based on user name? Well I can always expose another API endpoint at the Users Service end which receives the query term, perform a text search over user names in the Users Service, and then return all user details which match the criteria. At the Purchase Service, map the relevant ids back to the right names and show them in the page. This approach is not ideal either.

Am I missing something? Is there another approach for implementing the above? Maybe the fact that I'm facing this issue is sort of a code smell? would love to hear other solutions.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. The font end application should be separate from the services. You should be able to make front end application changes without changing a service. 

For the purchase screen the purchase service and users service should be called to get the data for the screen. Alternatively a separate api could be put in front of the services  which will call both services and then return the data back to the screen. 

Take a look at the diagram [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html#DecentralizedDataManagement) which shows how it should work.

Comment: Here is the API pattern: http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

Comment: I have exact confusion, can't believe it's almost 8 years later.

Answer (score 19):

This seems to be a very common and central question when moving into microservices. I wish there was a good answer for that :-)

About the suggested pattern already mentioned here, I would use the term Data Denormalization rather than Polyglot Persistence, as it doesn't necessarily needs to be in different persistence technologies. The point is that each service handles its own data. And yes, you have data duplication and you usually need some kind of event bus to share data across services.

There's another option, which is a sort of a take on the first - making the *search itself* as a separate service.

So in your example, you have the User service for managing users. The Purchases services manages purchases. Each handles its own data and only the data it needs (so, for instance, the Purchases service doesn't really need the user name, only the ID). And you have a third service - the Search Service - that consumes data produced by other services, and creates a search "view" from the combined data.

Answer (score 4):

It's totally fine to keep appropriate data in different databases, it's called [Polyglot Persistence](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html). Yes, you would like to keep user data and data about purchases separately and use message queue for sync. Millions of users seems fine to me, it's scalability, not design issue ;-)

In case of search - you probably want to search more than just username, right? So, if you use message queue to update data between services you can also easily route this data to ElasticSearch, for example. And from ElasticSearch perspective it doesn't really matter what field to index - username or product title.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use both approaches. Sometimes i have another service which is sitting on top on x other services and combines the data. I don't really like this approach because it is causing dependencies and coupling between services. So in general, within my last projects we tried to stick to polyglot persistence.

Also think about, if you need to have x sub http requests for combining data in some kind of middleware service, it will lead you to higher latency. We always try to cut down the amount of requests for one task and handle everything what is possible through asynchronous queues. ( especially data sync )

Answer (score 0):

If you conceptualize modules as the owners and controllers of the data they work on, then your model must also communicate that data out of that module to others. In contrast, the modules in a manufacturing process have the access to change data without possessing and controlling it.

Microservices is an architecture for **distributed** processing, like most code, where modules pass the data around to work on it. From classic articles by Harvard Business Review and McKinsey on the subject of owning members of a supply chain, I identified complexities arising from this model and wrote an article teaching programmers what you need to know: http://www.powersemantics.com/p.html

Manufacturing is an architecture for **integrated** processing, where modules work on the data without passing it around from point to point. This can be accomplished by having modules configured to access the same memory, files or database tables. My architecture shows how to accomplish this on memory via reference properties.

When you consider "exposing an API at the Users Service end which brings back user details based on given ids", you need to be aware that creates what HBR calls "irreversible" complexity, which I've dubbed centralization complexity. Don't build A->B (distributed) systems, because you can't decentralize them later after failing to separate requirements. Requirements in production processes represent user instructions, and centralized modules only enable you to change the wrong users' processes. In other words, centralized modules don't document user groups or distinguish them from derived-product-users.