# Is it bad to join data in an application, and not in a database in microservice architecture?

Tags: join, architecture, microservices

For example, I have Author service and Book service. Both services have a separate database.
In the Book service, I need to join each book with one author. I think I have 3 ways:

1. In the Book service, I can communicate with the Author service using some communication channel: TCP, Message Broker, etc.
   And I can fetch authors from the Author service, and then make JOIN in the Book service (in the application instead of the database)
2. In the Book service, I can define a view database, which is a read-only replica of the Author service database (https://microservices.io/patterns/data/cqrs.html). And then, in the Book service, I can make JOIN using the database.
3. I can join data on the front-end side. On the front-end I can make two HTTP requests to the services, and then join the data on the front-end.

Which way is better?

Comment: None of the above. You should have an application DB service for for all queries re data shared by any related services implementing your application. Learn about the reasons for & uses of DBMSs. PS If a "service" affects another "service" in what way are there 2 "services" rather than 1? (Rhetorical.) It's not clear what the scopes of your Author & Book services are & whether they are even needed given an application DB service. PS This is actually what your link is saying to do.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, it is not quite clear to me where and for what purpose you actually need the joined data from the two sources - for example: does the *book service* perform an operation for which it needs data from the *author service* or would it just pass through the joined data to the frontend?

In general, it is fine that each service owns its associated data and another service (in your case: the frontend) retrieves and uses data from several sources. So in my opinion, option 3 is probably a good choice.

Due to the objective of [loosely coupled services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)), I would not recommend creating replicas of one service's data in another service, because you would have to make changes in more than one place in case of a change in your data model. You might also run into problems such as consistency of data.

See also the discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460485/microservices-architecture-cross-service-data-sharing), [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368279/microservices-and-data-storage) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143180/is-it-bad-idea-to-share-almost-identical-data-among-microservices-for-item-rec) about data sharing between microservices.

Answer (score 1):

(1) I'd avoid, because it introduces an undesirable degree of coupling between your services. Unless your use case dictates that giant listings of book titles are to be accompanied by choice specific data from the author db (for example the author's name), I'd avoid replication, particularly an entire database otherwise once again you're introducing hard coupling. Even though propagation of specific data elements like a name is fine (you're already propagating author id), both the service and it's database should enjoy the freedom to evolve independently and be deployed independently.  So (2) is out.

That leaves us with (3), which works very well with GUI based front-ends, where a panel fills in the author details with a rest call, while another panel below asynchronously makes a call to fill in the list of books.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 3 is what you need to take. In order to have it implemented, you need an Experience API (a microservice) which UI will invoke and then that Experience microservice, as the name is self-explanatory will pull data from downstream microservices, massage, scrub and render the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm "architecturally against" the idea of having a "Book Service" or an "Author Service."  *(Of course I know you're using this as an example.)*

Here's why:  "A Book, like an Author, is *a Thing."*  Whereas, "a Service" is not a Thing.

A "service" should either provide something or do something.  And, whatever it does or provides should be *complete* and *self-contained.*  Books have Authors and Authors write Books and so the two cannot be separated.  Don't put the onus on the consumers of your service(s) to have to access several different services to get what they need.  If you see that your services have "overlapping concerns," as in this case, then it's a giveaway that your architecture is flawed.